# [E200]:An unexpected exception occurred attempting to save the send definition:

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect, distributed-marketing

I have failed to create and save "salesforce sends" in Marketing Cloud and the following error message has shown up:

[E200]:An unexpected exception occurred attempting to save the send definition: An error occurred when attempting to save an existing salesforce send definition. See inner exception for detail.

Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: When creating Salesforce Sends Emails, apparently if the "Tracking destination" is anything else other than "Salesforce Mass Sends" the error will pop out. 

Therefore make sure to select first "Salesforce Mass Sends" before clicking on the "Edit Recipients"

Answer (score 1):

Just got the same error. Changing the DE type to sendable solved the problem.